# How to link anchor to a show and hide function on another page

Tags: jquery, html

I am running into a problem with an anchor tag. I want to be able to to link from one page to a certain part of a page that is hiding due to its functions. 
Here is the html

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a class="button" id="showdiv1"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/collaborate-b.svg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a class="button" id="showdiv2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/organize-b.svg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a class="button" id="showdiv3"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/accelerate-b.svg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pillars-layout">
                <div id="div1">Content One</div>
                <div id="div2" style="display:none;">Content Two</div>
                <div id="div3" style="display:none;">Content Three</div>
            </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
$('#showdiv1').click(function() {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function() {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});

$('#showdiv3').click(function() {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
});})
```

So in this case I am hiding elements and showing. But lets say when I come from my other page I want it to display Content Two with an anchor. Would You know a solution for this?

Comment: So is what you have the HTML of both pages combined? Or is it all of the relevant HTML on the same page?

Comment: @dukedevil294 So its a custom WordPress site. Both have separate templates. So its linking from another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm assuming that the link to the page looks something like: www.mydomain.com/page#div2

```
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.href,
    hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
    if(hash !== ""){
        $(".pillars-layout").children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('#' + hash).show();
    }
});
```

This would go on the page that is loaded after the link is clicked.

Comment: So that worked great but it now displays it under div1 that is active already. Is there a way to hide div1 and display just div2 so they are not stacking. Thanks for the code, You are Awesome!

Comment: @Zachary I updated my answer so that if there is a hash present in the url then it will hide all the divs on page load and then show the relevant one.